# Spring will not start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am receiving the following error when trying to start Spring (https://github.com/jonleighton/spring). I am running it in a Vagrant box with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 12.04.

```
    vagrant@rails-starter-box:/vagrant/ticketee$ spring start
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:85:in `unlink': Text file busy - /vagrant/ticketee/tmp/spring/spring.pid (Errno::ETXTBSY)
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:85:in `unlink'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in set_exit_hook'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:84:in `each'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:84:in `block in set_exit_hook'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:34:in `initialize': Operation not permitted - /vagrant/ticketee/tmp/spring/spring (Errno::EPERM)
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:34:in `open'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:34:in `boot'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:15:in `boot'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client/start.rb:13:in `call'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client.rb:23:in `run'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spring-0.0.8/bin/spring:4:in `'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/spring:19:in `load'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/spring:19:in `'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Vagrant's read-only file system you need environment set the variable SPRING_TMP_PATH to somewhere outside of the /vagrant directory

run this at the command line

```
mkdir ~/spring_tmp; export SPRING_TMP_PATH=/home/vagrant/spring_tmp
spring start
```

then run

```
spring status
```

if spring is now running then add the following line to ~/.bashrc

```
export SPRING_TMP_PATH="/home/vagrant/spring_tmp" # Temp PATH for spring
```

Credit for this goes to George Brocklehurst

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with RSpec. I had to mount /windows via SMB (cifs) from a shared folder. I also had to change the permissions on the shared folder to grant write access. You can either grant Full Control to Everyone, or Full Control to your Windows user, but then you have to mount with permissions.

> mount -t cifs //10.0.2.2/aidc    /windows -o credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,uid=500,gid=500

You also have to install Samba (cifs?) too in your Virtual Box.

I heard vboxfs is really bad and doesn't handle a large number of files.